# Biphasic dose-response: what model to use in R drc() package?

Tags: r, model, dose-response

I am trying to model a dose response curve that has two phases (i.e. two steps).

[GraphPad Prism has the model in their workflow](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_biphasic_dose_response_2.htm), but I am trying to accomplish the model fitting in R. With the objective of getting two slope coefficients (Hill coefficients)

My data looks like the figure in the linked prism website. Below is some scramble data I am testing the `drc()` package with.

```
dose <- c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60)
response <- c(0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.05, 0.09, 0.129, 0.129, 0.146, 0.214, 0.310, 0.361, 0.373, 0.378)

model <- drm(response ~ dose, fct = LL.4(), type = "continuous") #What model instead of LL.4 would be appropriate here? 

plot(model, type = "all")
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that the [`drc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drc) has a built-in function to handle that type of (somewhat unusual?) dose-response relationship, but you can always use the `nls()` function in R to do your own fit, based on the [equations provided by GraphPad Prism](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_biphasic_dose_response_2.htm).

I copied your `dose` and `response` vectors into a data frame `df`, changing their names to "x" and "y" respectively to save some space. The equations then have the following general form:

```
y ~ bot +                                 # bottom asymptote
    (span * frac)/(1+(EC50_1/x)^NH1) +    # fit for first phase
    (span * (1-frac))/(1+(EC50_2/x)^NH2)  # fit for second phase
```

where `span` is the difference between the bottom and top response asymptotes, `frac` is the fraction of total response associated with the first phase of the dose-response relationship, the `EC50`s are the half-maximal doses for each phase, and the `NH`s set the corresponding steepness of each dose-response phase.

Note that you can't use any data involving 0 values of the dose, as you divide the `EC50`s by that. That's a problem whether you use this form of the relationship or use the [log-concentration form](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_biphasic_dose_response.htm) instead.

Nonlinear models often need a lot of care in finding useful starting values. You plot the data and see how well some starting-value guesses provide a curve that lines up approximately with the data. Once you succeed, you can use those as starting values for the software to refine.

That was particularly the case here. The following eventually seemed to work well enough for a guess:

```
plot(response[2:13]~dose[2:13],log="x") # omitting 0-dose values
curve(0.02 + 
      0.15/(1+(20/x)^4) + 
      0.22/(1+(45/x)^20),from = 0.1, to = 60, add=TRUE)
## not shown
```

leading me to propose the following `start` values for the model:

```
testModel <- nls(y ~ bot + 
                    (span * frac)/(1+(EC50_1/x)^NH1) + 
                    (span * (1-frac))/(1(EC50_2/x)^NH2), 
                     data=df[2:13,], start = list(bot=0.02, span=0.34, frac=13/34,
                                                  EC50_1=20, EC50_2=45, NH1=4, NH2=20))
```

which, unlike many prior attempts, led to a model that seemed to fit OK.

```
coef(testModel)
#        bot       span       frac     EC50_1     EC50_2        NH1        NH2 
#  0.0191114  0.3596578  0.3222598 18.0440873 42.1122681  6.1691780 14.6180345
```

Those seem like very high `NH` values, leading to very steep slopes of the curve's phases. Default guesses are typically values of 1.

There might be a way to write this type of model in a way that makes it compatible with the `drc` package, but I haven 't used the package in a while and, even if it's possible, I don't have any experience with writing models for it and such a question is probably too software-specific to be on-topic here.

Be careful with this type of model, if these values are representative of data you have in practice. Here you are trying to estimate 7 coefficients based on only 12 observations. Even if the `dose` values are exact, unless the outcome measurements are extremely precise that type of coefficient/observation ratio is likely to lead to severe overfitting. You might fit the current data, but the results might not extend well to new observations. John von Neumann allegedly claimed that he could both [fit an elephant and make its trunk wiggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%27s_elephant) with only 5 coefficients (although, in fairness, the eventual implementation of his claim required complex-valued coefficients).

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Turns out the non linear model you used is defined in the `drc()` documentation. The `twophase()` function is pretty much the equation defined in Prism (but with different parameterization). I tested both, and I get the same coefficients. 

A note on the outcome measurements, I have an error of around 5% in triplicates. But even if they are that precise, there is still overfitting. Would increasing observations in itself address this?

Comment: @jackkelly glad that you found that function already built in. In this type of experiment there is usually greater biological than technical variability. I'd prefer doing more biological replicates (different batches of cells/animals/whatever) rather than more technical replicates within a single experimental run. That will tell you more about the underlying, biologically important, variability in EC50 values and Hill coefficients. Overfitting leads to increased variance among new experiments, so the variance among biological replicates will also contain overfitting-related variance.

Answer (score 1):

For dose-response curves you can ask @HarveyMotulsky who visits here every now and then. He is an expert in curve fitting, as he wrote GraphPad Prism. The Prism guide section has a bit on biphasic curves: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_biphasic_dose_response.htm